# Better Elasticsearch client to connect AWS Elasticsearch from JAVA Spring-boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I am a new bee for `Spring-boot`. I need to query `AWS Elasticsearch`. The endpoint looks like below

```
https://vpc-xxxxxx.es.amazonaws.com
```

I'm not sure which is the better client to opt for, as there are multiple options. I checked `spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch` and `org.elasticsearch.client`. Looks like the clients are taking port of cluster nodes' (9300). Since I'm using AWS ES I don't have access to nodes' port. Here the port used is `443`. Please suggest me the better ES client which supports AWS ES Service.

Comment: did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using port 9300, it indicates that you are trying connect TransportClient remotely to an Elasticsearch cluster

According to official [ES doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/transport-client.html),

> Deprecated in 7.0.0. The TransportClient is deprecated in favour of
>   the Java High Level REST Client and will be removed in Elasticsearch
>   8.0.

**And even according to this [blog](https://www.elastic.co/blog/the-elasticsearch-java-high-level-rest-client-is-out), the high-level client will eventually replace the transport client in the future.**

**So, if you are developing a new application, its better to use  [Java High Level REST Client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high.html)**

Now, as you have got your endpoint, you can now communicate to Elasticsearch using the HTTP protocol.

You will be able to see cluster information

[image]

You can now easily create index, index data in it, delete index ,etc.

For eg. In the following images shown, I have created an index `customer`

[image]

[image]

[image]

- To know more about how you can use Java High Level REST Client with Spring Boot to talk to AWS Elasticsearch, you can refer this [article](https://medium.com/echoenergy/how-to-use-java-high-level-rest-client-with-spring-boot-to-talk-to-aws-elasticsearch-9e12571df93e)

You can also refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33558093/how-to-talk-to-aws-elasticsearch-service-using-elastic-java-client)

Comment: @rmn.nish did you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from you and if it's helpful, please dont forget to upvote and accept :) –

Comment: how you authorize/authenticate your request in AWS elasticsearch instance? In the blog it shows without any authorization, any idea how to implement that?

Answer (score 1):

The port 9300 indicates that you are trying to connect via transport. This is one way of connecting to elasticsearch which is [deprecated from v7](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/transport-client.html). You want to use the rest (http) client, which communicates via http calls.
This is now the recommended way of communicating with elasticsearch. Transport used to be the recommended for performance reasons, but not anymore.

You did not mention your elastic version, but one option is to use the [high level java rest client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high.html).